# Strange mouse pointer behavior along right edge of screen Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: gnome, display, 19.10, mouse-pointer

I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.10 (upgrading from 18.04) and I've noticed some strange behavior when the mouse cursor touches the right edge of the screen. If you just touch the pointer to the edge, it will come out at a different point along the same edge. If you drag a selection box into the edge it will erratically jump around.

I installed Pop!_OS 19.10 to play around and noticed the identical thing happening. Since it happened in both (and wasn't present in 18.04 when I was using it as a daily driver), it must be an issue with later versions of Ubuntu. It's nothing serious, but it certainly gets annoying. I've tested several different mice/trackpads and all have been the same.

I've attached a GIF of the issue. I apologize if the mouse pointer is hard to see; the resolution isn't amazing. You may have to open it in a new tab and zoom in a bit.

[image]

Comment: probably not but check display properties is not on adjust for tv. that on mucks up my stylus pen calibration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I've found a solution. My `xorg.conf` has two `Screen` and in the `ServerLayout` screen 1 was set to `RightOf` screen 0. I only have one monitor, but it seems my mouse was entering a second display that wasn't actually there. After making a hacky edit to `xorg.conf` to offset them, it works fine.

Here is the edited `ServerLayout` section:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 2000 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection
```

Comment: I am having this same problem (20.04 in my case though), but I do not seem to have an xorg.conf.  There is a folder /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d which has several files in it, but I did not see a ServerLayout section in any of them.  I'm a bit new to Ubuntu myself, so thought I'd see if you have any ideas I can try before I post my own question.  It is a different version of Ubuntu, so probably a different solution is needed anyway.