# Mouse jumps to new position at right edge of screen Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, display, mouse-pointer

On a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04, when the mouse cursor touches the bottom two-thirds of the right edge of the screen, it jumps up to a different position about one third of the distance from the top of the screen.

The behavior seems to match another Ask Ubuntu topic here: [Strange mouse pointer behavior along right edge of screen Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195338/strange-mouse-pointer-behavior-along-right-edge-of-screen-ubuntu-19-10)  The solution mentioned in that topic was to make edits to the xorg configuration which had two screens, despite the user having only one monitor.  Note that in my case, I also only have one monitor.

Unfortunately, the solution from that Ask Ubuntu topic does not apply to 20.04, because there is no xorg.conf as far as I can tell.  There is a folder /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d which has several files in it, but I did not see a ServerLayout section in any of them.  Does anyone have suggestions for how to debug this problem in 20.04?

-- EDIT -- I found xorg.conf under /etc/X11 (somehow I missed it when I was searching before).  The so-called "hacky edit" solution from the linked topic also worked for me in 20.04.  However, if anyone can suggest a more elegant answer, I'll award the bounty to the best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I've found a solution. My `xorg.conf` has two `Screen` and in the `ServerLayout` screen 1 was set to `RightOf` screen 0. I only have one monitor, but it seems my mouse was entering a second display that wasn't actually there. After making a hacky edit to `xorg.conf` to offset them, it works fine.

Here is the edited `ServerLayout` section:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 2000 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection
```

Hope it will helpful.

Comment: Ok, now I feel stupid.  I somehow missed xorg.conf when I was searching for it, but just now I found it under /etc/X11.  The above edit from the linked question was the solution.  I'll award this answer the bounty unless a more elegant solution is suggested.